# Adding item to python thread's queue from within a function with the thread

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, queue

I'm building a robot head that listens and speaks via an AIML bot whilst a camera picks out faces with opencv2. I have various threads running so that it can look, listen, speak and move its mouth, eyes and entire head with servos simultaneously. The threads need to interact with each other and I have code that does this. This "listening" thread needs to pass data back to a main module. This is working fine:

```
class listen(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, workQueue, queueLock):
        super(listen, self).__init__()   
        self.workQueue = workQueue
        self.queueLock= queueLock

    def run(self): # "listening" thread  
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
        # do lots of things......
        self.workQueue.put(some_data)  # put data in queue
```

My problem is that my "listening" thread calls a function "say()" and it is from within *this* function that I need to do the workQueue.put() rather than within the run(self) definition above. I cannot fathom the syntax of how to reference self.workQueue.put(some_data) from within the say() function or if indeed it is possible. Hope this makes sense.